# Trimming (removing) certain characters from the end of a string variable

Tags: string, stata

I have a string variable in Stata which includes the company names. Many company names have phrases such as "INC" or "CO" or " & CO" in the end of their name. I want to remove all such characters from the end of the company name. I have tried several tricks but so far I have been unable to find a clean and effective fix for this problem.
I found several suggested fixes on the web but they all result in broken outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not give a data example; or examples of the code you tried; or any details of problems that you experienced.

```
replace company_name = trim(itrim(company_name)) 

foreach bad in INC CO "& CO" { 
    local length = strlen("`bad'") 
    replace company_name = substr(company_name, 1, strlen(company_name) - `length') if substr(company, -`length', `length')  == "`bad'" 
}
```

is what springs to mind.

EDIT The code should look for "& CO" before it looks for CO. Otherwise this works with a concocted example.

Comment: Thank you Nick. I tried this code for a string like "ABC & CO". It removed "CO" but still kept "&".

Comment: We need to see a data example and the exact code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different solution and this one seems to work flawlessly. The downside is that you need to repeat the same process several times. So if it can be converted into a loop things will get easier.

```
gen one = substr(company, 1, strpos(company, " & CO")-1)

replace company=one if !mi(one)

drop one

gen one = substr(company, 1, strpos(company, " CO")-1)

replace company=one if !mi(one)

drop one

gen one = substr(company, 1, strpos(company, " INC")-1)

replace company=one if !mi(one)

drop one
```